# SSMS's Linked Informix Server: I See Only Tables and Views, Not Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, informix, linked-server

I searched but did not see a dead-on answer to this question:

Why are stored procedures (under something like "Programmability / Stored Procedures") not listed along with the Tables and Views of an Informix linked server, within Microsoft's SSMS Object Explorer?

I have God privileges, RPC In/Out set to TRUE, and I eat occasionally a vegetable.  No matter how I create, via the SSMS interface, the linked server for Informix, all I get back is a list of Tables and Views, even though I may execute an Informix stored procedure from an SSMS query window.

P.S.  From the same window, I have even SELECTed the stored procedures' info, from the Informix-side sysprocedures and sysprocbody tables.

Comment: I think this is by design. Link server only allows to see the data, not any business logic.

Comment: That has been my guess, but I wonder if SQL clients other than SSMS are able to see, for example, linked servers' SP names and the scripts inside of them.

Is there some option in SMSS that I must turn on, in order to see such things?

Comment: I'm not aware of any options. try to set RPC and RPC-OUT in linked server option to see how it works. I don't have environment to try it.

Comment: See above.  Both set to TRUE.